# Disable datalist input if there is no option data

Tags: php

I have datalist like this :

```
<input type="text" list="colours" id="txt">
<datalist id="colours">
   <?php foreach ($kondisi as $kondisi) { ?>
   <option data-value="<?php echo $kondisi->nama_kondisi ?>" value="<?php echo $kondisi->id_kondisi ;?>"><?php echo $kondisi->nama_kondisi ?></option>
   <?php  } ?>
</datalist>
```

The option that datalist has was populated from a foreach loop using php.
How do I disable the datalist input, if the data that foreach loop's result is null/none using jquery ?

like for example

Have Option

```
 <input type="text" list="colours">
```

No Option

```
<input type="text" list="colours" disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: Try to keep your PHP and HTML separate and you would be able to achieve what you are trying to do much easier.

Comment: Any example ? i usually write code like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***If you want to disable it then do like below:-***

```
<?php if(count($kondisi)>0){?>
    <input type="text" list="colours">
    <datalist id="colours">
       <?php foreach ($kondisi as $kondisi) { ?>
       <option data-value="<?php echo $kondisi->nama_kondisi ?>" value="<?php echo $kondisi->id_kondisi ;?>"><?php echo $kondisi->nama_kondisi ?></option>
       <?php  } ?>
    </datalist>
<?php }else{?>
    <input type="text" list="colours" disabled="disabled"/><!-- or use autocomplete="off"-->
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of keeping your PHP and HTML separate:

```
<?php 
$option="";

foreach ($kondisi as $kondisi) { 

if($kondisi != 'null' || $kondisi != 'none'){

$option .= '<option data-value="'.$kondisi'.->nama_kondisi" value="'.$kondisi.'->id_kondisi">'.$kondisi.'->nama_kondisi</option>';

}else{

$option .= 'your disabled option code here...';

}

  } 

?>


<input type="text" list="colours">

<datalist id="colours">

<?php echo $option; ?>

</datalist>
```

Comment: I have edited my question, please check it. Is there a way if i am using jquery

Comment: If your question has changed to a jQuery related question, you can post a new question and since it'll be a javascript/jquery related question then you can provide a working FIDDLE too and someone would be able to help you.

Comment: i changed my mind, i dont need jquey for this question, @alive to die have answered first